# How to make custom footer section stick to bottom of page in Pages 5?

Tags: pages

I'm trying to use Pages 5 to design my invoices. I have a fixed header section for the address and the logo, then a table which is part of the text flow and automatically continues on the next page.
However I would like to have a footer area attached to the bottom of the last page which contains my banking information.
If the table is short, I would like this information to stick at the bottom of page 1. If the table content becomes longer, I would like to have it at the bottom of page 2.

Possible?

Comment: If the table extends do you want the footer at the bottom of page two *and page one* or just page two?

Comment: *only* at the bottom of the last page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is currently not possible.**

You can have it at page 1 and page 2 using a normal footer as you're probably aware, but not *automatically* move to the last page of a document. You can do it manually as you're also probably aware by using the section inspector, but that's still not automatic and would require you to delete it from page 1 and then add it back to page 2.

You can notify Apple that you would like this feature implemented using their Pages feedback page:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/pages.html